# Should the count parameter be declared directly before the ellipsis (...) in a variadic function?

Tags: c++, c, x86

This is the implementation for the `va_start` macro:

```
#define va_start(list, param) (list = (((va_list)&param) + sizeof(param)))
```

As you can see, the `va_start` macro is returning the address of the first byte in the variable list of arguments by assuming that it exists directly after the `count` parameter (I mean by the `count` parameter the name of a parameter that I declare that I will pass to the number of arguments).

So if I am using in addition to the `count` parameter other parameters, Should the `count` parameter be declared directly before the ellipsis (...)?

Comment: It might be defined that way on your implementation. Don't rely on it, and don't forget to call `va_end(x)` too.

Comment: What "count" parameter?  There is no parameter that automatically receives the number of arguments.

Comment: There is no convention here, so instead of referring to your personal convention that no one knows about, how about showing some code?

Comment: I'm with @BenVoigt on this one.  I've never seen a use of var args with a count parameter: there's either a format string, like in `printf`, or a sentinel value, like in `execl`.  Like Ben, I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`va_start()`](http://www.sbras.ru/cgi-bin/www/unix_help/unix-man?stdarg+3) should always be called with the **last named parameter**, so for example

```
void function(int x, int y, int z, ...)
{
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, z);
    .
    .
    .
    va_end(ap);
}
```

> So if I am using in addition to the count parameter other parameters, Should the count parameter be declared directly before the ellipsis (...)?

Yes, if you want to use `va_start()` this way

```
va_list ap;
va_start(ap, count);
```

Comment: don't leave off `va_end(ap)`.